# Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: android, junit, nullpointerexception, robotium

I'm getting error when i'm trying to run a Andriod JUnit test at my Activities:

```
Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wecharades/com.example.wecharades.views.GameDashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at java.util.TreeMap$1.compare(TreeMap.java:72)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at java.util.TreeMap$1.compare(TreeMap.java:70)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at java.util.TreeMap.find(TreeMap.java:277)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at java.util.TreeMap.findByObject(TreeMap.java:351)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:177)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at com.example.wecharades.model.Model.getTurns(Model.java:258)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at com.example.wecharades.model.DataController.getTurns(DataController.java:460)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at com.example.wecharades.presenter.GameDashboardPresenter.createDashboard(GameDashboardPresenter.java:53)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at com.example.wecharades.views.GameDashboardActivity.onStart(GameDashboardActivity.java:48)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1940)
05-31 15:57:19.159: E/AndroidRuntime(22342):    ... 11 more
```

The thing is that just some of my tests are getting this error message, while some works fine.
They all link to the same project and all tests use ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.
Even though i just got the skeleton for some tests and all of the are based on the same code, some of them just won't work and keeps getting the error.

Here's a very simple code that gets this error:

```
public class GameDashboardActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<GameDashboardActivity> {

    public GameDashboardActivityTest() {
        super(GameDashboardActivity.class);
    }
    private GameDashboardActivity activity;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        activity = getActivity();
        assertNotNull(activity);
    }

    /**
     * Run the void updateScore(int currentPlayersScore, int otherPlayerScore) method test.
     * @throws Throwable 
     *
     */
    public void testUpdateScore_1()
            throws Throwable {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

}
```

The GameDashboardActivity

```
package com.example.wecharades.views;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.wecharades.R;
import com.example.wecharades.presenter.GameDashboardPresenter;

/**
 * View which displays the game dashboard
 * @author weCharade
 */
public class GameDashboardActivity extends GenericActivity {

    private TableLayout myTable;
    private TextView title;
    private TextView yourScore;
    private TextView opponentsScore;
    private GameDashboardPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, new GameDashboardPresenter(this));

        //Set the title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_screen);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar_home); 

        //Get references to instances
        presenter = (GameDashboardPresenter) super.getPresenter();
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        yourScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourScore);
        opponentsScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opponentScore);
        myTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){

        super.onStart();
        presenter.createDashboard(myTable);

    }

    /**
     * Updates both players' scores
     * @param currentPlayersScore
     * @param otherPlayerScore
     */
    public void updateScore(int currentPlayersScore, int otherPlayerScore) {

        yourScore.setText(Integer.toString(currentPlayersScore));
        opponentsScore.setText(Integer.toString(otherPlayerScore));

    }

    /**
     * Set title of the Game dashboard
     * @param title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {

        this.title.setText(title);

    }

    /**
     * Go to StartActivity
     * @param v
     */
    public void onClickHome(View v){

        presenter.goToStartActivity();

    }

    @Override
    protected RefreshProgressBar getProgressBar() {
        return null;
    }
}


Model.java    
    /**
     * This class stores all the data available in the game locally.
     *  This class exist to reduce the number or request to parse.com
     *
     */
public class Model implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8167671678222883966L;
    //The name of our model save file
    private static final String     SAVE_FILE = "model.save";
    //Stored variables to use in other classes - should maybe be in another class.
    public static final int         
    FINISHEDGAMES_SAVETIME          = 168
    , FINISHEDGAMES_NUMBERSAVED     = 10
    , INVITATIONS_SAVETIME          = 72;

    /*
     * A variable that can be changed in order to purge the model - this is done manually when needed!
     *  When this is set to true, the model will be forced to be recreated. This is done to purge the
     *  Model and retrieve a mirror of the database information, while preserving login status 
     *  (and avoid having to reinstall and log in and out again). This MIGHT be implemented as a feature later. 
     * 
     *  -- DO NOT FORGET TO RESET THIS AFTERWARDS! --
     */
    private static boolean          PURGE = false;

    //A variable to check if model is already saved.
    private boolean                 SAVED = false;
    //A variable which is called when a user logs out 
    // - the model exists a moment so we may finish any queries first
    private static boolean          RECREATE = false;

    //Two maps for games for increased speed and ease of use
    private TreeMap<Game, ArrayList<Turn>> gameList = new TreeMap<Game, ArrayList<Turn>>();
    private TreeMap<String, Game> gameIdList = new TreeMap<String, Game>();

    //Two maps for player names and id:s. The second one is used for increased speed and ease of use
    private TreeMap<String, Player> storedPlayers = new TreeMap<String, Player>();
    private TreeMap<String, String> storedPlayerNames = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    private Player currentPlayer = null;

    // Invitations are stored locally in two lists
    private LinkedList<Invitation> sentInvitations = new LinkedList<Invitation>();
    private LinkedList<Invitation> receiveInvitations = new LinkedList<Invitation>();

    //Singleton
    private static Model singleModel;

    private Model(Context context){
        //Creating a file to save to
        if(context != null){
            saveModel(context);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to get the singleton instance of the model where necessary.
     * @return the Model
     */
    public static Model getModelInstance(Context context){
        if(PURGE){
            //If the PURGE variable is set to true (done manually), the model will be recreated
            eraseModel(context);
            singleModel = null;
            PURGE = false;
        }
        if(singleModel == null){
            //Try to load from storage
            singleModel = loadModel(context);
        }
        if(singleModel == null || RECREATE){
            //If there were no previous models present, create a new one
            singleModel = new Model(context);
            RECREATE = false;
        }
        return singleModel;
    }

    /**
     * A method to save the current model to memory.
     * @param context - used to retrieve a save location
     */
    public void saveModel(Context context){
        if(!SAVED && context != null){
            try {
                FileOutputStream ops = context.openFileOutput(SAVE_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(ops);
                oOut.writeObject(singleModel);
                oOut.close();
                SAVED = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("IO - Model save", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to load a model form memory
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    private static Model loadModel(Context context){
        Model singleModel = null;
        if(context != null){
            try {
                ObjectInputStream oIn = new ObjectInputStream(context.openFileInput(SAVE_FILE));
                Object obj = oIn.readObject();
                if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(Model.class)){
                    singleModel = (Model) obj;
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1){
                Log.d("IO - Model load", "No file found");
            } catch (IOException e2){
                Log.d("IO - Model load", "IOException");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e3){
                Log.d("IO - Model load", "ClassNotFound");
            }
        }
        return singleModel;
    }

    /**
     * Called to erase the current model from memory and disk.
     * @param context
     */
    private static void eraseModel(Context context){
        if(context != null){
            File modelFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), SAVE_FILE);
            if(modelFile.delete()){
                Log.d("Model - File:","Removed file");
            }
            RECREATE = true;
        }
    }

    //Games ---------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Updates a list of games. If a game is not existant, it will be added to the list. 
     * @param games
     */
    public void putGameList(ArrayList<Game> games){
        for(Game game : games){
            putGame(game);
        }
        SAVED = false;
    }

    /**
     * Updates a game in the internal list of games. Will also create new games that does not exist.
     * @param game - the game to be updated
     */
    public void putGame(Game game){
        //This is actually kind of fast, although it might look a bit weird.
        ArrayList<Turn> tempTurns;
        if(gameList.containsKey(game) && gameList.get(game) != null){
            tempTurns = gameList.get(game);
            gameList.remove(game);
            gameList.put(game,tempTurns);
            gameIdList.put(game.getGameId(), game);
        } else{
            gameList.put(game, null);
            gameIdList.put(game.getGameId(), game);
        }
        SAVED = false;
    }

    /**
     * Return an ArrayList with current games
     * @return - an arraylist containing games
     */
    public ArrayList<Game> getGames(){
        return new ArrayList<Game>(gameList.keySet());
    }

    /**
     * Gets a game from its game id
     * @param parseId
     * @return a Game, or null it does not exist
     */
    public Game getGame(String parseId){
        return gameIdList.get(parseId);
    }

    /**
     * Removes a game form the model
     * @param game - the game to be deleted
     * @return - true if the game was in the list, false otherwise
     */
    public void removeGame(Game game){
        gameIdList.remove(game.getGameId());
        gameList.remove(game);
        SAVED = false;
    }

    /**
     * Use to update a single turn of a game. This will add a turn if it does not exist,
     *  as well as update its state if it is existant.
     * @param game - the game in question
     * @param turn - the turn of the game
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if no game is found
     */
    public void putTurn(Turn turn){
        if(turn != null){
            if(!gameIdList.containsKey(turn.getGameId()))
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            Game game = getGame(turn.getGameId());
            ArrayList<Turn> listOfTurns = gameList.get(game);
            if(listOfTurns == null){
                listOfTurns = new ArrayList<Turn>();
                gameList.put(game, listOfTurns);
            } else if(listOfTurns.contains(turn)){
                //If the turn contains the turn, we must delete it first
                listOfTurns.remove(turn);
            }
            listOfTurns.add(turn);
        }
        SAVED = false;
    }

    /**
     * Updates a list of turns at once - the existing list will be overwritten.
     * @param turnList
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if no game is found
     */
    public void putTurns(ArrayList<Turn> turnList) throws NoSuchElementException{
        //Do not simply replace the list, as this might cause problems with the amount of turns etc.
        for(Turn turn : turnList){
            putTurn(turn);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get a list of turns for a game
     * @param game - the game
     * @return - an arraylist of turns
     */
    public ArrayList<Turn> getTurns(Game game){
        return gameList.get(game);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current turn from the model
     * @param game - the game to fetch from
     * @return a Turn
     */
    public Turn getCurrentTurn(Game game) {
        if(game != null){
            ArrayList<Turn> turns = getTurns(game);
            if(turns != null){
                for(Turn t : turns){
                    //Find the turn with CurrentTurnNumber
                    if(t.getTurnNumber() == game.getTurnNumber()){
                        return t;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Players ---------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Puts a player in stored players 
     * @param player - the player to be stored
     */
    public void putPlayer(Player player){
        //The data for a player should always be updated
        storedPlayerNames.put(player.getName(), player.getParseId());
        storedPlayers.put(player.getParseId(),player);
        SAVED = false;
    }

    /**
     * Puts a collection of players into the model
     * @param players - a collection of players
     */
    public void putPlayers(Collection<Player> players){
        storedPlayers.clear();
        storedPlayerNames.clear();
        for(Player player : players){
            putPlayer(player);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used to get a player representation from a username
     * @param username - the player username
     * @return a Player, or null if no player was found
     */
    public Player getPlayer(String username){
        Player retPlayer = null;
        if(storedPlayerNames.containsKey(username)){
            retPlayer = storedPlayers.get(storedPlayerNames.get(username));
        }
        return retPlayer;
    }

    /**
     * Used to get a player representation from a username
     * @param parseId - the player id
     * @return a Player or null if not found
     */
    public Player getPlayerById(String parseId){
        return storedPlayers.get(parseId);
    }

    /**
     * Designates a player as the current player. If the player does not exist in cache,  
     *  it gets added.
     */
    public void setCurrentPlayer(Player player){
        currentPlayer = player;
        putPlayer(player);
        SAVED = false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the logged in player player (ParseUser)
     * @return A Player representation of The current player, or null if this player does not exist.
     */
    public Player getCurrentPlayer(){
        return currentPlayer;
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the current player entirely from the model. Should be done when user logs out.
     */
    public void logOutCurrentPlayer(Context context){
        eraseModel(context);
    }

    //Invitations ---------------------------------------------------------------
    //Received invitations are not needed here, as they should allways be fetched from the database.

    /**
     * Set all sent invitations from this player. This replaces the local version of this game.
     * @param invitations - The invitations to add
     */
    public void setSentInvitations(LinkedList<Invitation> invitations){
        if(invitations != null){
            sentInvitations = invitations;
        } else{
            sentInvitations.clear();
        }
        SAVED = false;
    }

    /**
     * Set all received invitations to this player
     * @param invitations - The invitations to add
     */
    public void setReceivedInvitations(LinkedList<Invitation> invitations){
        if(invitations != null){
            receiveInvitations = invitations;
        } else{
            receiveInvitations.clear();
        }
        SAVED = false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a list of Invitations sent from this device.
     * @return A List containing invitations.
     */
    public List<Invitation> getSentInvitations(){
        return sentInvitations;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a list of Invitations the current player has received
     * @return A List containing invitations.
     */
    public List<Invitation> getReceivedInvitations(){
        return receiveInvitations;
    }

}
```

GenericActivity.java

```
/**
 * Abstract class which holds implementations of, for the activities, generic methods
 * @author weCharade
 */
public abstract class GenericActivity extends Activity {

    //Presenter object, declared protected and therefore enabling access to extending classes
    protected Presenter presenter;

    /**
     * onCreate-method which sets the presenter
     * @param savedInstanceState
     * @param presenter
     */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, Presenter presenter) {

        //Only send the Bundle-object to the super class 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    /**
     * This method will return a ProgressBar in the form of a spinner.
     * Use this spinner to give a visual queue to the user that something is happening
     * in the background. 
     * @return The progressbar of the view.
     */
    protected abstract IProgress getProgressBar();


    /**
     * Called to show progress spinning when waiting for the server
     */
    public void showProgressBar() {
        if(getProgressBar() != null) {
            getProgressBar().show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called to hide progress spinning when the server has responded
     */
    public void hideProgressBar() {
        if(getProgressBar() != null) {
            getProgressBar().hide();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Private help method to get all clickable objects in a list from a view.
     * @param view
     * @return an ArrayList with all Views within the parameter view
     */
    private ArrayList<View> getAllChildren(View view) {

        //Check if the view is a "single" view
        if (!(view instanceof ViewGroup)) {
            ArrayList<View> viewArrayList = new ArrayList<View>();
            viewArrayList.add(view);
            return viewArrayList;
        }

        ArrayList<View> result = new ArrayList<View>();

        /*  
         * Add all children of the ViewGroup and eventually return the 
         * ArryaList containing the views.Childrens of a children in a ViewGroup are
         * added to the list by recursively calling the method.
         */
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {

            View child = vg.getChildAt(i);

            ArrayList<View> viewArrayList = new ArrayList<View>();
            viewArrayList.add(view);
            viewArrayList.addAll(getAllChildren(child));

            result.addAll(viewArrayList);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Enable all clickable objects in view.
     * @param view a List containing all elements of the view to enable
     */
    public void enabledView() {
        List<View> viewList = getAllChildren(this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));

        //Loop through the list of views and enable them.
        for (View child : viewList) {
            child.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Disable or disable all clickable objects in view.
     * @param view a List containing all elements of the view to disable
     */
    public void disableView() {
        List<View> viewList = getAllChildren(this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));

        //Loop through the list of views and disable them.
        for (View child : viewList) {
            child.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show a toast to the user.
     * @param msg
     */
    public void showToast(String msg) {

        //Declare and get reference to a LayoutInflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        //Inflate custom Toast layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_success, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
        text.setText(msg);

        //Create Toast, set duration and layout
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }

    /**
     * Show a message to the user, most often an error. Uses a dialog-box with one button.
     * @param error
     */
    public void showNegativeDialog(String negativeTitle, String negativeText, String buttonText) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        //Actions to set custom Dialog layout and set properties
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_negative);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));  
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);        

        TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.negativeTitle);
        title.setText(negativeTitle);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.negativeText);
        text.setText(negativeText);

        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
        button.setText(buttonText);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Show a message to the user, most often an error. Uses a dialog-box with two buttons.
     * @param negativeTitle
     * @param negativeText
     * @param buttonText1
     * @param buttonText2
     */
    public void showNegativeDialog(String negativeTitle, String negativeText, String buttonText1, String buttonText2) {

        //Create new Dialog-object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        //Actions to set custom Dialog layout and set properties
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_negative_two);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.negativeTitle);
        title.setText(negativeTitle);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.negativeText);
        text.setText(negativeText);

        Button button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
        button1.setText(buttonText1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.back);
        button2.setText(buttonText2);

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Show a positive dialog to the user. Most often a success message
     * @param error
     */
    public void showPositiveDialog(String positiveTitle, String positiveText, String buttonText) {

        //Create new Dialog-object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        //Actions to set custom Dialog layout and set properties
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_positive);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));               

        TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.positiveTitle);
        title.setText(positiveTitle);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.positiveText);
        text.setText(positiveText);

        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
        button.setText(buttonText);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Show a progress dialog to the user. 
     * @param error
     */
    public void showProgressDialog(String positiveTitle, String positiveText, String buttonText) {
        //TODO: To be implemented
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        //Save the model to disk whenever an activity is closed.
        presenter.saveState();
        super.onStop();
    }

    /**
     * Get the presenter associated with an activity.
     * @return A presenter
     */
    protected Presenter getPresenter(){
        return presenter;
    }

}
```

The NullPointerException seems to occur at the getActivity() part, but I have no clue why.
Any ideas?

//Felix

Comment: You need to post the `com.example.wecharades.views.GameDashboardActivity` class as well. The issue seems to be that the `DataController` asks the `Model` (through `Model.getTurns` for a turn that doesn't exist. Do you allow `nulls` to be inserted into the model?

Comment: and `GenericActivity`... The issue is with your `Model` so please post that as well.

Comment: I found the problem. You where right, I got a NullPointerException from the getTurns method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause-chaining in Java seem to confuse you. You'll need to dive down to the last cause to see the root cause. In this case it was:

```
at com.example.wecharades.model.Model.getTurns(Model.java:258)
```